# Как обеспечить требуемый порядок инициализации переменных из разных единиц трансляции?

Tags: c++

Есть файл first.cpp:

```
int first()
{
    return -1;
}

static int f = first();
```

Есть файл second.cpp:

```
int second()
{
    return -1;
}

static int s = second();
```

Все это собирается в один исполняемый файл.

```
$ g++ first.cpp second.cpp main.cpp -o main
```

В силу ряда причин нужно, чтобы `first()` исполнялось гарантированно до `second()`. Как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, разумеется, если говорить конкретно о показанном Вами коде, то в нём нет возможности зафиксировать порядок инициализации — ведь переменные находятся в **разных единицах трансляции**.

Можно только выдумывать какие-нибудь ухищрения. Например, экспортнуть переменные и проинициализировать их в одной функции.

Глобальная статическая переменная — вообще странная вещь. Попробуйте заменить их на Синглтоны (их-то легко в нужном порядке проинициализировать).

---

Самое безболезненное решение: заменить переменные на функции со статической переменной внутри.

---

*Судя по всему, у Вас баг в архитектуре ;)*.

Comment: >> Судя по всему, у Вас баг в архитектуре ;)
+1 ;) Возможно, её просто напросто нет.

Comment: да какая разница - синглтоны или не синглтоны? все равно глобальные переменные в разных единицах трансляции и порядок будет не определен.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но Синглтоны — это не глобальные переменные. Ни разу. Совсем.

Comment: Два _разных_ синглтона - это разве не два разных объекта? Да и вообще они то тут каким боком? Приведите простенький пример.

Comment: @IAZ Обычный Синглтон Майерса будет инициализироваться не в какой-то неведомый момент времени рантаймом, а совершенно чётко — при первом обращении. Соответственно, достаточно на запуске программы организовать к этим двум объектам «фейковые» обращения в правильном порядке. Идея-то за этим стоит поражающая своей неглубиной: любая статическая глобальная переменная всегда с лёгкостью заменяется на Синглтон Майерса.

Comment: Ну т.е. я синглтон как-то, возможно, погорячившись привёл… ну… как наводку на правильную идею. Можно, например, сделать статическую функцию.

Comment: @kirelagin все гораздо проще как выяснилось после того как подумал :) см. мой обновленный ответ

Comment: @IAZ, ой, а чего Вы сразу-то не сказали? =) Мне эта идея пришла [судя по логу изменений] десять минут назад и я её тоже дописал в свой ответ)).

Answer (score 1):

Никак не получится, порядок инициализации глобальных переменных зависит от компилятора. Была ссылка на документ об этом, но сейчас ее нет у меня. При желании самостоятельно можно найти.

UPD: если убрать глобальные переменные (но не потеряв их значений), то можно гарантировать порядок вызова данных функций.

```
int first()
{
    static int f = -1;
    // ...
    return f;
}
```

Есть файл second.cpp:

```
int second()
{
    static int s = -1;
    // ...
    return s;
}
// где угодно
int f_s()
{
    first();
    second();
    return -1;
}

f_s();
```

Comment: От компилятора? Серьёзно? )))

Comment: Ладно, раз реакции никакой нет, я поясню свою мысль, чтобы другим читателям было понятно. В данном случае речь идёт о разных единицах трансляции — у компилятора нет никакой возможности повлиять на порядок инициализации. Единицы трансляции компилируются раздельно и абсолютно независимо!

Comment: Теперь по поводу глобальный переменных в одной единице трансляции.  ISO/IEC 14882:2003, раздел 3.6.2: «… Objects with static storage duration defined in namespace scope in the same translation
unit and dynamically initialized shall be initialized in the order in which their definition appears in the
translation unit. …».

Comment: @kirelagin а от кого же?

Comment: В конкретно данном случает — от рантайма. А в одной единице трансляции — от Стандарта ;).

Comment: Вы же не думаете, что при запуске программы переменные инициализирует компилятор?

Comment: От компилятора (точнее в данном случае от линковщика) зависит в каком порядке будет слинкован код, ну и, соответственно, какая будет последовательность вызовов определится во время компиляции (линковки).

Comment: Ну так давайте не будем писать линковку в скобочках после компиляции, поскольку два этих действия не имеют НИЧЕГО общего. Кроме того, я точно не знаю механизма, которым линковщик сообщает рантайму список переменных, требующих инициализации. И я не знаю механизма, которым рантайм выбирает из этого списка порядок переменных. И, догадываюсь так, Вы тоже не знаете. Так что я бы на Вашем месте не стал делать таких заявлений.

Comment: Ну да, я и никто другой не знает, только компилятор и линковщик. О чем собственно и написал. Других заявлений от меня вроде как не было.

Comment: Так, ещё раз: от компилятор никаким образом не зависит, в каком порядке будет слинкован код. Это зависит от линковщика. Кроме того, порядок инициализации переменных никак не зависит от порядка линковки кода. Это зависит от рантайма.

Answer (score 1):

Если глобальные переменные находятся в разных единицах трансляции, то порядок их инициализии неопределён. Если они находятся в одной единице - они инициализируются по мере их ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ в этой единице.

Answer (score 1):

Порядок инициализации зависит от порядка объектных файлов при линковке. По крайней мере на линуксе. Прямой или обратный - можно выяснить, написав экспериментальное приложение. Наблюдал оба варианта.

Далее. Можно утилитой nm к примеру получить список импорта и экспорта из каждого объектного файла. Делаем предположение, что если А импортирует глобальный объект из Б, то Б должен инициализироваться раньше. Логично?  Строим граф зависимостей объектных модулей. Сортируем топографической сортировкой. Если есть циклы( иногда бывает, глобальный объект используется вне секции глобальной инициалиции ), то их надо разруливать ручками, передавая в алгоритм сортировки правила типа "А после Б".
В итоге получаем отсортированый список объектников, Инвертируем если надо.

Линкуем и вуаля.

Все это завернуто у меня в мейкфайл и работает пятый год. Не жалуюсь :)

Answer (score 1):

Цитата:"Самое безболезненное решение: заменить переменные на функции со статической переменной внутри."

ИМХО не такое уж безопасное.

Во первых,  обращение к глобальным данным через такие функции будет "по требованию". Это означает, что порядок инициализации каждый раз будет зависеть от исходных данных, то есть порядок будет разный. Если в конструкторах глобальных объектов будут сайд-эффекты, то... даже Голливуд позавидует чудесам в вашей программе.

Во вторых. Отсутствие связи "по конструктору"  не означает отсутствие связи "по деструктору". Реальный пример. Строки в программе реализованы с помощью глобального строкового аллокатора. Но в конструкторе другого объекта строки не используются. Поэтому объект может быть инициализирован ДО строкового аллокатора. Деструкторы вызываются  в обратном порядке. Но этот объект в деструкторе использует строки для печати статистики. А строкового аллокатора уже нет - разрушен, ибо разрушение идет в порядке обратном инициализации...

Answer (score -1):

И я вставлю свои пять копеек. Как правильно сказали два предыдущих оратора, порядок инициализации глобальных статических переменных не определен. Зато порядок уничтожения переменных гарантированно обратный порядку инициализации.

---

Конечно, имеется ввиду случай, когда переменные определены в разных единицах компиляции. Поэтому хорошая практика — не использовать глобальные статические переменные пользовательских типов вообще, либо определять их в одной единице трансляции.

Comment: Порядок инициализации глобальных статических переменных ещё как определён!

Comment: Да? Даже если они находятся в разных единицах компиляции?

Comment: Ну предполагается, что обсуждать порядок инициализации переменных в разных единицах трансляции здоровые люди не будут. Кроме того, в Вашем утверждении нет такой оговорки, стало быть, Вы утверждаете, что он вообще всегда не определён, что есть неправда.